# Snap individual vertex of the selection to closest vertex

Tags: modeling, geometry, vertices

I want each individual vertex of my selection to snap to the closest unselected ones, so they superpose each other.

Im aware of the vertex snapping utility along the "closest" mode but it only work on "one" vertex, and thus will move the entire selection.

I could do it by hand but it would become tiresome with hundred of vertices.

Precision: I'd like it to work in UV editor too.

I hope I'm clear, Thank you.

Comment: maybe show a screenshot (or link to a hosted image) of the scenario here.

Comment: @Kaleb Its bit confusing as in what is it u want to achieve. If you could give an example scenario. And what is the end result you want to achieve it should help find solution

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind if the extra vertices are removed, you can use remove doubles and in the tool settings (<kbd>F6</kbd>), set the merge distance to something higher (probably in the range of .01 and .1). This will merge close vertices that are closer than a the merge distance.

[image]

Comment: Is there a similiar feature when manipulating the vertices in the UV window? And no other feature that'd do the same without removing vertices?

Comment: Yes, there's a remove doubles feature in the UV editor W > Remove Doubles. It works exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you this feature works perfectly with the "unselected" option, however it would be nice if an equivalent wich doesnt remove vertices exist.

Comment: In the UVs? I don't think you can delete vertices in the UV editor.

Comment: Yes I meant in the 3D modeling view. Indeed, none UV are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the *Selection to Grid* option from the (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) [snap menu](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap#Snap) could be of use? It moves each selected object/point to the nearest grid point.

The grid can be configured in the [Display panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#Display) of the [3D View's Properties shelf](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#View_Properties_Panel).