# How to add vertex precisely at crossing edges?

Tags: edit-mode

Let's forget 3D for a while and imagine it all happens in 2D.

I have two edges that are crossing each other, they are on exactly the same plane when it comes to Z axis (z-dimension is thus not important). How do I add a common vertex to those two edges precisely in the spot where they cross each other?

For example:

[image: crossing edges]

Comment: you are right, btw. I found tinyCAD addon the most helpful solution, thanks

Comment: @jubi Could you add an additional answer on tinyCAD to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/add-point-to-intersection-of-two-edges ?

Comment: @stacker sure, I added it