# How to merge overlapping edges into one?

Tags: vertices, edges

I have two overlapping vertices.

[image: before]

I want to merge these two vertices into one.

[image: after]

How can I do this automatically? I have a large model with a lot of overlapping edges like these. It will be also very useful that I could merge vertices with parallel edges within a given distance. Is there any tool for that?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/add-point-to-intersection-of-two-edges

Answer (score 4):

Doing so in the past would have been painful and given you a lot of bad geometry.  If you tried to animate it you'd get horrible mesh deformations.

Now, you might be able to get good results with the intersect tool added in 2.71.

Here's a YouTube video about how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWSiRDw_tKE

Basically you tell Blender to calculate the intersection of the two meshes, then delete the over lap, and finally you can bridge the two in a number of different ways (including the bridge tool, but in your case probably merging each vertex pair).

There might still be some odd topology to clean up, and it might not animate cleanly.. but I think cleaning this up will be easier than other methods of getting the vertices in the same place.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in my case the intersection tool does not do what I want. It doesn't work properly when you have two overlapping edges. It generates more points and edges what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with that issue before, I think what I did to solve it was Boolean, then Remesh, and Decimate to planar, and finally triangulate.  This should combine all of your closely connected faces or edges, even from multiple objects, and then leave a clean optimized mesh at the end.  Sometimes this can make specific edits a little bit more difficult in the future, so you have the option of not triangulating until you're finished.

Doesn't always work, though, due to Remesh being a bit finicky.