# Connect vertices where they would meet, not fill?

Tags: modeling

Lets say I have a plane, and I extrude two edges, it would produce a gap. I would like to fill this gap by using the projected intersection of the new outer edges. Shown in the right most example of the image below:

[image]

I can extrude the two vertices and fill the area, making the desired outcome. If I had used `F` to fill *before* I've made the vertices meet, the result would be a square with diagonal edges (the empty area would be filled and turned into a triangle, not a square).

For my situation, I am trying to do the same, except I am using a circle. If I simply hit F to join the two vertices I get the result seen on 3.
How can I connect the two vertices where they meet (shown in 4). Are there any tools to get the intersection or fill it automatically?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add point to intersection of two edges](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/add-point-to-intersection-of-two-edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender, navigate to File > User Preferences... > Add-Ons and search for "f2". Enable this add-on:

[image: F2]

So now, if you have the following extruded plane:

[image: Extruded plane]

Select the vertex on the innermost corner of the face you want to create:

[image: Selected vertex]

Now, press the F key, and the F2 add-on will complete the face, where the vertices should meet:

[image: Pressed F]

Comment: This doesn't work on other than square geometry.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try the [tinyCAD addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD).

Select the two extruded edges then choose *w->TinyCAD->VTX Auto* and you will get a vertex joining the two where they would intersect.

[image]