# How to make a point out of 2 intersecting lines?

Tags: modeling

I have 2 lines, and I want to get the point where they intersect. I am looking to have a point created on the point of intersection. How can this be done?

Comment: Oh. It is a dupe. My bad. Do I delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two line maybe not even intersect, not even in 2d if they are parallel, well there is cheat for it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_at_infinity

In blender we work with vectors in a 3d place and not with real numbers but with floats. So a pure mathematical solution is maybe unusable, I wrote this because the question is pure mathematical. If we rephrase it for 3d modeling:

Can I make a vertex at the intersection or mutually closest point of two edges. We will get a duplicated question:
[How can I add vertices to intersection of two edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/add-point-to-intersection-of-two-edges?rq=1)