# How to merge two crossing faces into one?

Tags: faces

I have made this simple shape from two planes, it has no volume.

[image: 2D shape in front ortho]

As you can see there are two faces that are overlapping in the center creating that weird square, which is not a face and cannot be deleted or dealt with.

[image: One of the faces selected in the edit mode]

So the question is, how can I remove that thing in the middle and make sure I'm dealing with just one face?(I've tried pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to combine two faces but nothing happens).

Comment: Don't think you can use Boolean for this. One option is to go with Knife Project from the top view (but planes have to be separated into different objects), another is using [tinyCAD](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2976/1245) addon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add vertices to intersection of two edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such task there are **Mesh > Faces > Intersect (Boolean)** and **Intersect (Knife)** tools in **Edit Mode**, but for your example they are not working as supposed to. Also with two separated shapes from your example **Boolean Modifier (Union)** isn't working as well. I can't say why, as I'm not using Booleans at all.

As a workaround you can make it using **Knife Project** tool.

1. Select one of your shape/face in **Edit Mode** then use <kbd>P</kbd> > **Selection**.

[image]

2. In **Object Mode**, select one object, then with <kbd>Shift</kbd> select second one and go to **Edit Mode**.
3. In the **Tool Shelf** choose **Knife Project**.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 but now select objects in different order.
5. Join both objects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
6. In **Edit Mode** select all then <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles** and use <kbd>X</kbd> > **Limited Dissolve**.

[image]

> Note: Consider using quad topology as this will save you some problems
>   later on. Working with ngons could be problematic.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Boolean 2D Union add-on](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.jp/2014/06/addon-boolean-2d-union.html) for this.

Select your mesh and press <kbd>W</kbd>. You will see new options in the Specials menu.

Choose Boolean 2D Union to merge the separate faces into one connected piece of geometry.

[image: Boolean 2D Union]

This is the result:

[image: Boolean 2D Union result]

Similarly, you can use the TinyCAD add-on's XALL function to do this with edges that don't have faces. (This add-on is bundled with Blender.)

[image: TinyCAD XALL]

TinyCAD XALL result (notice the new vertex in the middle):

[image: TinyCAD XALL result]