# How to merge all the faces

Tags: faces

I have made a road with the addon. When i go in edit mode all the faces overlapping each other. Is there any way to merge or combine or boolean tool that can merge or combine all the face and make a single face which look clean in object mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems a bit complex but try edit mode intersect tooks, it is in the mesh menu iirc.

Comment: @m.ardito In edit mode with face selected i hit ctrl+f . With Intersect with knife no result as it is. With intersect with boolean everything disappear

Comment: @m.ardito file is attached plz check

Comment: Maybe experiment with simpler setups first. See this also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90055/how-to-merge-two-crossing-faces-into-one/90058#90058

Comment: @m.ardito i tried it but did not work and to some it work it took long time

Comment: I tried your file, frankly it's a bit a mess... around 50% faces have inverted normals, and so many of them are overlapping (not just crossing) in so many weird ways... I guess you didn't build this by hand... whatever was the tool, it did an horrible job...

Comment: @m.ardito I made with the addon. It gave me curve and in curve tab i extruded to make flat. Then i converted that curve to mesh and i got this over lapping faces. Is there any weld addon so that i can weld all the face

Comment: do you have the file where those were still curves? there could be another better way, maybe...

Comment: Can you post a link to the addon please?

Comment: @batFINGER this is the video and in description u can find the addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaYkN7cEEuo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is a crazy idea. As I said above in comments, "your file, frankly it's a bit a mess... around 50% faces have inverted normals, and so many of them are overlapping (not just crossing) in so many weird ways... I guess you didn't build this by hand... whatever was the tool, it did an horrible job.."

But, if you really like this shape you have now, except it's made from a spaghetti mess of dozens of separate "roads", and you wish to have a single connected mesh instead, here is how you could do it.

To do what it came to my mind, you need to export this 2D object as SVG, then use another tool, like Inkscape, to make the union in 2D, then reimport the united SVG in blender, as a single curve object that you could convert again to mesh (ALT-C) and thus have a single, connected mesh. I told you it was crazy...!

Except... blender has no svg export...

Wait, but there's a freestyle svg export addon!

Here is what I did.

- I used "blender render" instead of cycles, aiming for better speeds.
- I activated the freestyle svg export
- I enabled freestyle and the freestyle svg export for the scene
- I used an orthographic camera (with sufficiently high orthographic scale) to render the whole "road" puzzle
- I set a very high render resolution (3840x 2160) but I'm not sure it's really needed
- then I hit F12 and waited the render to finish
- after the normal render, freestyle adds a contour to the rendered objects: the freestyle svg export addon converts the freestyle outline to svg...

when the render finished, I found a 0001.svg file in /tmp,

then I opened that svg in Inkscape and, after some cleaning, I used the Inkscape "union" command. Then saved the new svg, and inmported in Blender. Here is the result:

[image]

a closer look

[image]

in edit mode:

[image]

Here is the file:
[image]

You could need to repeat and master this until satisfied, but at least you now have a way...

Comment: I concur that the original model is a mess... As an alternative to your answer you could set an orthogonal camera looking down on the model. Render that as an image, and trace that image in inkscape (or illustrator) it so that it becomes a path that can be exported as SVG

Comment: So finally u got it. Really thanks for the efforts u have taken. Why there is no addon which export svg. I tried that but my resolution was just 1024 so i quit from that method. If any body interested to make that addon convert or export the file to svg not with camera view directly as we export model. It will be great relief.

Comment: i found svg file export option mention below in answer

Comment: @cegaton I initially thought of tracing the render, but I thought freestyle svg export quality could be less dependent on render resolution... also atek's answer points to an even better way, using UVmap svg export option, which I didn't know, and it could be totally independent from the render!

Comment: After exporting in svg why output is in curve and why not as a mesh.

Answer (score 2):

Export uv as svg file

1. Go to top view and press U and select project from view

[image]

2. Open the uv window and go to uv-> Export Uv layout

[image]

3. In the export window change from png to svg (scalable vector graphic) and click export uv layout at right hand.

[image]

4. Now import or place the svg file in Illustrator or gimp (i use illustrator). Select all and unite. Now u get a complete single vector.
5. Save in svg format.
6. Import the saved svg file in Blender.

Final Result

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice. I didn't know about this UVmap SVG export option... that seems much better, and maybe the result is independent from render resolution? but it is not new in 2.79, my 2.76b already has it... I just never use that option. Thanks for pointing out! Lastly, Gimp is not useful, as you need a vector program, instead Inkscape will do this easily. It's a pity that blender still has no "2d union" like those other programs...