# Possible to make Vertices from overlapping Edges?

Tags: mesh

I tried to figure out how to make vertices from two overlapping edges. I want the exact point they overlap to become a vertex, but I can't seem to find a solution to the problem.

[image]

Comment: to make an edge from 2 overlapping vertices? don't you want to make a vertex from 2 overlapping edges instead?

Comment: Ye sorry misformulated :) I need a vertex

Comment: so install the TinyCAD addon, then select all, press W > TinyCAD > XALL, all edges intersections will give vertices, but you'll have to recreate faces.

Comment: perfect mate! exactly what I wanted, sad I didn't know about this addon long ago! God this will save me billions of hours!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add vertices to intersection of two edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos agreed, but I think the answers there may be unnecessarily complicated, in some situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the *[TinyCAD](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD/)* addon, then select all, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *TinyCAD* > *XALL*, all edges intersections will give vertices, but you'll probably have to recreate faces.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, since everything is flat, the quickest option might be to use Knife Project.

- Select the components you want to intersect with one another (as separate objects if you like), and <kbd>X</kbd> delete > 'Faces Only' to produce edge-only versions. (This is not always necessary, but I've found it gives the most reliable results.)
- Arrange those components above a blank  projection target.
- In Object Mode, select first the components, and then the blank, so the blank is active.
- Put the blank into Edit Mode.
- In an orthogonal view, straight down through the components onto the blank..
- .. in the tool region > Mesh Tools panel, find and hit 'Knife Project'

[image]

Vertices will automatically be formed at the intersections of your component's edges, in the projection.