# Adding a vertex onto an angled edge in precise X position

Tags: vertices, edges, knife-tool

I'm designing a part for 3D printing, but I do not know how to cut an angled edge at a precise absolute X position. I marked in red the place where I would like to insert a vertex. It's exactly 2 units (millimeters) from the left. So far I was unable to achieve this with desired precision.

[image: Scene with point marked in red]

**EDIT**

**First attempt.** Using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to move the vertex along the line and snapping to another vertex failed because apparently this tool uses local reference system.

[image]

**Second attempt.** using TinyCAD plugin. Worked perfectly!
I created a second edge that intersected the angled one, and used XALL to insert a vertex on the intersection.

[image]

Comment: TinyCAD solution will work for this if you extrude that vertex down https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges/21264#21264. Vertex slide doesn't use snapping to other geometry hence it's not the best choice for precise work in this case.

Comment: @MrZak Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? It worked perfectly!

Comment: Not going to add it since I think it might be a duplicate of already asked question here like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges or alike. Add answer yourself instead if you wish

Answer (score -1):

You could subdivide the edge to add a vertex. Select the vertex and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide the vert. Make sure snapping is set to vertex and then click on the vert shown at 2 units above. This should line up the lower vertex on the angled line with the vertex above

The vertex above could be place at 2 units with snapping set to increment absolute grid.

**Answer above incorrect. New solution:**

Ok this one bugged me as it should be possible to do this. I turned on edge length in the overlay

[image]

I subdivided the angled edge to create a vert and then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and dragged the vert to the starting vert on the edge. I am working in m so in the image you can see 0m.

[image]

With the vert still selected I dragged it back along the angled edge whilst holding shift to get a more precise value. I moved the vert until it was at 0.5m

[image]

Should be able to use this technique for other stuff

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I edited the question with description of my attempt.

Comment: sorry about that and when I think about it even if you could snap it would not have produced the correct result. Will also look at TinyCad - good luck

Comment: I know you already have a solution but original answer edited with hopefully a workable solution without an add on.

Comment: Unfortunately your way requires use of calculator :) To achieve `X = 2mm` on a `30deg` angled edge I need to calculate `2mm / cos(30deg)` so the edge needs to be  `2.309mm` long I use EditTools2 plugin and it's "Set Edge Length" tool to do similar thing precisely.

Comment: Thanks Filip. I had not used set edge length and just tried it, works great